# how to show a marker in the center screen with google map + mobile Secncha touch

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation, sencha-touch, extjs

I wrote map code which is working properly in sencha-touch framework.
I need some thing like [wikimapia.org](http://wikimapia.org) with a fixed cross or any obbject on middle but map be draggable. Then I can click on the object and show the address.

Any help please ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out my own answer here on a similar question

- [How Can I Get marker on current location in map in Sencha-Touch2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333076/how-can-i-get-marker-on-current-location-in-map-in-sencha-touch2-0/10333449#10333449)

Additionally, I also have set the current location as a `marker` to be on the center of map. So your issue of marker being at the center of screen is also resolved.

You can create an `infoWindow` and open it on `click` listener of the marker.
Like this,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(someMarker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.setContent('_Place Address_');
   infowindow.open(map, someMarker);
});
```