# How to get the center coordinate of the map(Ext.map) in sencha touch 2?

Tags: google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I use an Ext.Map to let a user choose a certain place and I want to get the coordinate (or the coordinate of the map center) that user chooses. Which method should I use? I can't find a proper one in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my answer to similar question given here. This will give you an idea.

- [How Can I Get marker on current location in map in Sencha-Touch2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333076/how-can-i-get-marker-on-current-location-in-map-in-sencha-touch2-0/10333449#10333449)

**EDIT:**

To obtain the position co-ordinates ( i.e latitude and longitude) from the textual address, you will need to use [**Google Maps Geocoding API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers or position the map.

Comment: Tks, but I think you misunderstands what I mean. Consider such a situation that the user wants to hold an collective activity and he will search in the map to find the place (not his current position). How can I get that coordinate from the map?